# Principal on gaining more height based on nested poles?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How do people design height gaining based on nested poles ?

Consider this picture (I made them) :
[image]

If I want to achieve height based on these 3 poles, how they should behave?

Is this how the behave?

[image]

I had been searching over the internet I haven't found the related material, and it's kinda hard what to type. I'm doing some tasks on designing a simple machine (no foundation knowledge but with will) and my English is sort of limited, especially to technical stuff but I hope you understand it .

*Imagine like there's somehow an auto increasing portable stair to get over the tree, the poles(both sides) are consisted of  poles fragment on each of them, how the fragments behave in this case.

Comment: could you provide a link to a application to this? Im not sure what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you not understand how to fix and release each of the inner parts?

Comment: I just want to figure out how they would be, I mean like (is there any application to such case), imagine like there's somehow an auto increasing stair to get over the tree. How would the poles behave in that case.

Comment: I just want to figure out how they would be, I mean like (is there any application to such case), imagine like there's somehow an auto increasing stair to get over the tree. How would the poles behave in that case

Comment: Based on your use of the word rotate in one sketch, are these nested screws, as opposed to poles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Telescoping* is the English term for this and a search for [telescoping mechanisms](https://www.google.com/search?q=telescoping%20mechanisms&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&gws_rd=cr#q=telescoping%20mechanisms&tbm=isch&pws=0&gws_rd=cr) will give lots of info on the various approaches.

A motor + transmission mechanism is called an actuator. So searching for [telescoping actuator](https://www.google.com/search?q=telescoping%20actuator&biw=1280&bih=610&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) will show you devices that automatically extend with some sort of external or internal control.

Comment: I really -really thank you!!!! By the way can they be *automation* system , I mean without help by manually pulling the both side of poles by hands? Like somehow the process is done by *gear/motor* mechanism?

Comment: Yes, we call that an actuator. I extended my answer.